# Yii2 query all get value in join

Tags: php, mysql, join, yii2

I have an database with tablenames like this: tbl_accessoires_1, tbl_accessoires_2 etc. In my main table is a column that gives me the number for the table I have to join. But how do I get this value if I use ->all().

This is my query:

```
$query = (new Query())
   ->select([
       'a.id id',
       'a.soort soort',
   ])
   ->from('auto_new a')
   ->leftJoin('tbl_accessoires_--soort-- acc', 'acc.id = a.id')
   ->all();
```

So the a.soort in the select must be at the --soort--
Is there any way to do this?

If I only get one car it is possible because I could get the soort value before this query. but how do I do this when I want to get all cars

Comment: This would be a kind of 'dynamic join' which is not possible, afaik. If the accessory tables are all of the same format I would merge them into a single table with an extra column (for 1, 2, 3, ...). Otherwise you could execute multiple queries if the performance is not an big issue (what I suspect).

Comment: It's not my own database. But I think I'll just make a new query then. Because when I use all() I don't really need this join.

Comment: It might be helpful to left join all the tables if there are not too many and select the values based on a if or case switch condition in your select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So because it's not possible in my situation I've just made a new query to get the options. This will do for now because I don't really need the options when I get all cars.